# Download large object from AWS S3

Tags: amazon-s3

I have an Angular web application in which allows users to download files locally (installers). Some files exceed 1.5 GB in size, which causes the browser to crash (Chrome) when using 'normal' s3.getObject(opts, function(err, data){}) calls, since the entire file binary data is cached....?

I have tried to use other techniques, like streaming (StreamSaver.js), but with no luck.

I am trying to chunk the file data, but in the follow code, the 'httpData' event does not get called until the entire file's binary data is loaded...which seems to defeat the purpose of chunking. I am not understanding this event, or I have something misconfigured.

```
cache.S3.getObject({ Bucket: 'anduin-installers', Key: filePath }) 
   .on('httpDownloadProgress', function (progress) {
       $timeout(function () {
          pkg.Download.Progress = Math.floor((progress.loaded / progress.total) * 100.0);
       });
   }) 
  .on('httpData', function (chunk, response) {
      console.log('???');
   }) 
  .on('complete', function (response) {
      $timeout(function () {
         pkg.Download.Active = false;
         pkg.Download.Progress = 0;
      });
  })
 .send();
```

Any ideas no how to make event 'httpData' fire as data chunks are received instead of waiting for th whole file? Or should I go with another solution?

Thanks!

Comment: If you're downloading files locally, why not just sign a URL and... let the browser download the file?  I'm sure you have a reason, but I don't know what it is.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  That is exactly what I ultimately did to resolve this issue.  I *think* I wanted to use the AWS API as an another layer of security until I can properly secure the website....but in the end this issue became a exercise in trying to understand why I couldn't make it work.

Comment: Based on this comment, you might find it useful to know (if you didn't already) that an ordinary browser download with a signed URL uses exactly the same API that the SDK uses.

Comment: Did not know..thanks for the heads up...I will research further for my own education.